# instant html class change by DOM manipulation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle, setstate, react-state

In React app I have a code to toggle html element's (let's call it element A) class when pushing a button. I do it by mutating a state which contains settings for the whole app. Then when the element A is rendered it checks the appropriate setting and apply or not apply the class to it.

This works, but it takes a long time to re-render everything and thus there is a lag between click and changes applied. So I thought to use a little hack here with classic DOM manipulation to first change class (to see changes instantaneously) and then let React re-render everything.

The issue I have is that the changes are not applied by DOM manipulation, but only later after re-render. When I comment the `setState` line, the changes are visible immediately.

My question is, how to achieve instant class change and what could be wrong here?

```
  const handleCollapseToggle = (i, el) => { 
    const helpToggler = document.getElementById(el);
    helpToggler.classList.toggle('is-hidden');
    console.log('test',helpToggler);

    const newCollapsed = Array.from(settings.collapsed);           
    newCollapsed[i] = !newCollapsed[i];                             

    const newSettings = {
      ...settings, 
      collapsed:newCollapsed
    }    

    setSettings(newSettings);

    //setTimeout(setSettings(newSettings), 10000);
 }
```

I have also tried the `setTimeout` to apply a new state (please see on the last commented line of code), but that did not work and even did take less then 10 seconds to re-render. Also the `console.log('test',helpToggler)` logs out the `'test'` word first and then the element itself later after re-render (on the same console log line).

Comment: Did you try to select an element using [useRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) that should solve the issue, I usually never had a good experience using native dom APIs directly to select & manipulate HTML as each renders updates HTML node object's reference. This should give you a clue if I understand your question right.

Comment: thanks for a hint, but the result is the same.

Comment: Welcome, I can relate, was doing something similar. Don't remember the details, but one more hint would be to try to put your function in `useEffect()`  if your case permits it and have ref object as a dependency. have some conditionals to see if this is the right time to run your function. Hopefully, this solves your issue.

Comment: I am afraid I can't work with useEffect as the function runs onClick and even if it would be there it would run after render

Comment: Okay, if I get the gist you want to toggle class and perform a few more tasks as well. I have used [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) it allows you to have any value type as className. What I remember doing in toggle scenarios was using an `object {'class-name': stateAsABool};` I might be going in different directions but perhaps you can have a state and update it accordingly. it will be more react compliant as well. and you may have to tackle your issue differently. Now I am out of options.

Comment: thanks for trying and good to know about this library, but sorry, not sure how that would help in this case. The issue is with a quick style application, not with a render itself which takes a long (I know, I have to look up the ways how to design app better to make this faster)